# Как продублировать определенное количество строк в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Необходимо создать несоколько дублирующих строк. Используется Oracle.

Для заданного количества одинаковых строк, используется параметр countRequests, который и определяет, сколько строк нужно создать на основе одной строки, которая уже есть в базе данных.
Строки будут отличаться только по полю id, inserted, last_modified (ну это поле условно будет отличаться, так как в момент вставки будет использоваться фукнция sysdate).

Данный код нужен чтобы создать набор данных, которые будут использоваться для ручного тестирования. Затем эти строки просто будут удалены.

Я пробовал решить эту задачу.

На вставку id, в базе данных используется триггер, который запускает заранее созданный  sequence generator.

Однако я также явно на каждой итерации, вызывал этот  sequence generator. Однако это не сработало.

Я использовал цикл, однако, за каждую итерацию, создается полная копия всех записей, а не одна запись с уникальными полями id, inserted.(база данных не имеет constraint на поле id).

Например, я задал 2 итерации, а в базе условно 20 000 строк, на выходе получаю 40 000 строк, полностью одинаковых, вот в этом и проблема.

А должно быть только 2 строки, как и задано по условию.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE name(countRequests IN NUMBER,  cardN IN VARCHAR2)
    IS

    ipAddress    varchar2(255);
    requestID    NUMBER;
    dateInserted Timestamp;

BEGIN
    SELECT id
    into requestID
    FROM (
             SELECT id
             FROM REQUESTS
             WHERE card = cardN
             ORDER BY inserted DESC)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('requestID : ' || requestID);

    SELECT IP
    into ipAddress
    FROM (
             SELECT IP
             FROM REQUESTS
             WHERE card = cardN
             ORDER BY inserted DESC)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ip Address : ' || ipAddress);

    dateInserted := (sysdate + interval '2' minute);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('dateInserted : ' || dateInserted);

    FOR counter IN 1 .. countRequests
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('counter : ' || counter);

            insert into LOGIN_BY_CARD_REQUESTS ( card, IP, INSERTED,
                                                LAST_MODIFIED)
            select
                   card,
                   IP,
                   (sysdate + interval '2' minute),
                   sysdate
            from REQUESTS
            where number = cardN
              and IP = ipAddress;

        END LOOP;
END;
```

Мне необходимо создать дубликаты только заданного количества строк, не больше не меньше.

При этому у них должен быть  уникальный id, поле inserted и lastModified должны отличаться.

Есть идеи как это сделать ?

Comment: Как у вас генерируется ID(сиквенс?). Как inserted и last_modified должны отличаться от исходной записи и между собой при добавлении? Кстати, поля ID я не вижу при вставке...

Comment: Описывайте задачу, а не только свои попытки её решить. [Проблема XY](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: при вставке записи, срабатывает триггер и id автоматически генерируется

Comment: inserted + искусственно увеличиваю время на каждой итерации на 1 или 2 минуты. Для last_modified Указывается timestamp на основе текущего отрезка времени, то есть когда происходит вставка записи(для этого использую sysdate).

Answer (score 0):

**1-й вариант**

```sql
create table apples
(
    ID       NUMBER,
    name     VARCHAR2(50),
    color    VARCHAR2(50),
    quantity int
);


INSERT into cpil.APPLES (id, NAME, COLOR, QUANTITY)
select 1 + LEVEL - 1, 'antonovka', 'green', 1
from DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Здесь используется способ хранения данных в видет иерархической структуры. В этом случае одно поле таблицы является ссылкой на другую (родительскую) запись в той же самой таблице.

**LEVEL** - это псевдо-столбец, в котором указывается уровень записи, по отношению к корневой записи.
*Например:*
1-ая запись будет иметь уровень 1, ее потомки - уровень 2, потомки потомков - уровень 3, и т.д..

1 + LEVEL - 1 - позволит получить идентификаторы записей с 1 по 10 включительно. Если это убрать и сделать (1 + LEVEL), тогда получим записи с 2 по 11.

**Недостаток** в том, что нужно самому выставить **id** последней текущей записи в таблице, от которой нужно сделать копии. Кроме того, нужно самому заполнить все поля, которые должны быть наборе данных, которые вы захотите добавить.

Это как один из варинантов дублирования строк, но под задачу описанную в вопросе, это не подходит.

**2-й вариант**

```sql
DECLARE

    nameCopy     varchar(255);
    colorCopy    varchar(255);
    quantityCopy int;

BEGIN

    SELECT name
    into nameCopy
    FROM (
             SELECT name
             FROM apples
             WHERE name = 'antonovka'
         )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('nameCopy : ' || nameCopy);

    SELECT color
    into colorCopy
    FROM (
             SELECT color
             FROM apples
             WHERE name = 'antonovka'
         )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('colorCopy : ' || colorCopy);


    SELECT quantity
    into quantityCopy
    FROM (
             SELECT quantity
             FROM apples
             WHERE name = 'antonovka'
         )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('quantityCopy : ' || quantityCopy);

    FOR counter IN 1 .. 5 LOOP

       quantityCopy := quantityCopy + 1;

        INSERT INTO CPIL.apples (id, name, color, quantity)
        VALUES (apples_SEQ.nextval, nameCopy, colorCopy, quantityCopy);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('counter : ' || counter);

    END LOOP ;
end;
```

Недостаток этого способа - он более громоздкий (по сравнению с предыдущим), однако результат подходит по вопрос заданный выше.